# drawing boxes in java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have wrote a program that simulates memory allocation with first fit and best fit algorithms .

Now I want to associate my program with a drawing of set of boxes representing available memory segments

**Before Allocation**

[image]

**After Allocation**
[image]

So it just redraws but resizes one box and colors it ... What is the easiest way to do so ?
I have a set of boxes with different sizes that will be drawn dynamically according to input when the user does some action one of the boxes will be resized and recolored and so on.

Comment: I find your screen shots slightly confusing in that it seems that the 3rd block moves up, while the 4th does not.  Would it not be more logical to have the 2nd block the same size, but part red and part black?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is best approached using graphics.

1. Instantiate a `BufferedImage` of a size to fit all boxes.
2. Get a `Graphics` instance by calling either of `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()`.
3. For each memory block:

   1. Call `Graphics.setColor(Color)` according to allocation status, then..
   2. `Graphics.fillRect(int,int,int,int)` or `fillPolygon(Polygon)` to draw the memory block.
4. If needed, use an `AffineTransform` to scale the sizes.  This would require a `Graphics2D` object to draw on.

Comment: +1 . In effect using a JLabel only for drawing a rectangle, wasn't a good advice.

Comment: @0verbose:  I realized I still do not understand the spec. well enough to give the *best* advice.  **If** the memory blocks can be rendered all the same size, a `JComponent` (or even easier a `JProgressBar`) could be used to represent each memory block.  Those could then be put into a `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` to organize the placement.  Drop the lot into a `JScrollPane` and the job is done.

Answer (score 2):

Use a JPanel as container with vertical <s>FlowLayout</s> BoxLayout, and add to it a JLabel for each memory block.

Comment: @0verbose all together nice answer except I must disagree with the use of FlowLayout in this case. Anyway +1.

Comment: is the label resizable and colorable ?

Comment: yes. the you can set bounds and colors. Anyway your question is a bit vague. Try something, then if you have problems post some code an we will be pleased to help you.

Comment: @Ahmed yea you can both change its color and size. Color using `setBackground(color)` method. Size using `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w,h))` method. IMPOTANT to actually see the background of a JLabel you must set it to opaque using `setOpque(true)` method, as by default it is false.

Comment: Ah , I am sorry if it is vague . I mean I have a set of boxes with different sizes that will be drawn dynamically according to input when the user does some action one of the boxes will be resized and recolored and so on.

Comment: no..i meant..your question is quite clear, but I can't post all the code you need to do that. I gave you some hints..now try to document a bit following these inputs. If you have problem with the code post again.

Comment: Flow layout doesn't calculated preferred sizes properly when you attempt to use it vertically. The components "magically" wrap to the next line when the width of the panel is reached. But you can never use a FlowLayout and invoke the pack() method to get the frame to size properly with vertical components.

Answer (score 2):

Use JPanel add JLabels like 0verbose but the layout to go with in my opinion is [BoxLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) or [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

With FlowLayout you would have to make sure the size of the container is of a proper width to place one component under another, as by default it places components in a row.

From Java tutorial about [FlowLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) "The FlowLayout class puts components in a row, sized at their preferred size. If the horizontal space in the container is too small to put all the components in one row, the FlowLayout class uses multiple rows."

Comment: I prefer FlowLayout. with rigida areas and glues it's very flexible layout manager, and he can achieve simply the result he want.

Comment: @0verbose I agree you can achieve it but you must remember about its specifics, and I feel other layouts are more appropriate here. I do not want to argue, because myself I would go with [TableLayout](http://www.clearthought.info/sun/products/jfc/tsc/articles/tablelayout/index.html) :)

Comment: @TableLayout... sorry..my fault. I often confuse BoxLayout with FlowLayout . Of course FlowLayout doesn't suit the requirements. I meant it. I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**If** the memory blocks can be rendered all the same size, a `JComponent` (or even easier a `JProgressBar`) could be used to represent each memory block. Those could then be put into a `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` to organize the placement.  E.G.

### MemoryAllocation.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

class MemoryAllocation {

    public static JProgressBar getMemoryBlock(int full) {
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(
            SwingConstants.VERTICAL, 0, 100);
        progressBar.setValue(full);
        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,20));
        return progressBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JPanel memoryView = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,10,1,1));

                Random random = new Random();
                for (int ii=0; ii<200; ii++) {
                    int amount = 100;
                    if (random.nextInt(5)==4) {
                        amount = 100-random.nextInt(75);
                    }
                    memoryView.add( getMemoryBlock(amount) );
                }

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, memoryView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Screen Shot

[image]